# Disable/Forbid Upwards name referencing

Tags: system-verilog, lint

Is it possible to disable Upwards name referencing in system-verilog? For example such that a lint error or compilation warning/error is raised if it's used in the source code?

Background: Using Upwards name referencing (as defined by *23.8 Upwards name referencing* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)) causes the module to be very dependent on the hierarchical position it's instantiated in. Therefore I want to avoid it in our codebase.

Comment: If this is for synthesizable code you will get an error as hierarchical references of any kind are not allowed. In testbenches, upward references together with the `bind` statement are very useful.

Comment: @Mikef It's unfeasible to review for every rule. I want an automatic way / tool configuration to detect it.

Comment: @dave_59 It is in testbenches and I know it would be useful. I tried to use it but it's unfortunately(!) incompatible with our workflow for other reasons (I have tried to change this workflow but it seems VERY difficult (affects many ppl on other sites)), that's why I would like to quickly fail if anyone at our site tries to use it.

Comment: @dave_59 also, upwards name reference only works if you know where the module is bind instantiated. if a print_module can be instantiated in both module_A and module_B then you can't know that parent module name nor the parent module instance name.

Comment: Any hierarchical reference could be an upward reference and you wouldn't be able to detect without full elaboration of the design. Also, the top-level module is actually an upward reference, so you would need an exception for that.

Comment: @dave_59 ah right, I guess there is no practical way to it. `$parent` would be great. Where do I propose a language feature? :)

Comment: Making a proposal through your tool vendor is your best bet. But you haven't really described what it is making it so difficult in your environment? And adding `$parent` would not prevent people from using the existing functionality.

Comment: Modules and instances have their named changed (prefixed/suffixed) in some flows, and therefore neither of those names can be used in upwards naming reference since the names are unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is possible in software with the right amount of resources. But the current SystemVerilog LRM does not have such a feature. A decent lint tool could implement such a check. But...

Any hierarchical reference could be an upward reference and you wouldn't be able to detect without full elaboration of the design. Also, the top-level module is actually an upward reference, so you would need an exception for that